# Server returned HTTP response code: 500 when we are sending Arabic language content

Tags: java

We are sending HTTPURLRequest to server.

When we are sending English content its working fine.But, when we are sending Arabic language content we are getting

```
Server returned HTTP response code: 500
```

We had written below code

```
connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();          

connection.setRequestMethod("POST");            
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");          
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + Integer.toString(SendRequest.getBytes().length));
connection.setUseCaches(false);
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setDoOutput(true);            
DataOutputStream dataout = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());  
dataout.writeBytes(SendRequest);
dataout.flush();
dataout.close();
BufferedReader bufferreader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), "utf-8"));
```

When I use `connection.getInputStream()` I am getting 500 error
We are using utf-8 also.But, still getting the error
can any one help me

Comment: You could use charset: ISO-8859-1 in content-type header.  Probably the special chars are producing problems.

Comment: I tried this didn't work still getting same error

Comment: Can you post the log in your server? and can you tell me if you have a load balancer like nginx.

Comment: The Arabic content converting like below testuser@esms.local#@#Test123#@#0503000857#@#~D8~AA~D8~AD~D8~AF~D9~8A~D8~AB~D8~B9~D8~B2~D9~8A~D8~B2~D9~8A ~D8~A7~D9~84~D8~B9~D9~85~D9~8A~D9~84 ~D8~8C ~D8~B4~D9~83~D8~B1~D8~A7 ~D9~84 ID ~D8~A7~D9~84~D8~AE~D8~A7~D8~B5 ~D8~A8~D9~83 ~D9~85~D8~B9 ~D8~A8~D9~86~D9~83 ~D8~B2~D9~8A~D8~B1~D8~A7~D8~AA . ~D8~A7~D9~84~D8~AA~D8~AD~D9~8A~D8~A7~D8~AA #@#0

Comment: Are you convinced that the server can handle the response?  Are there any errors from the server?  That's where the issue lies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use a library to escape the special chars:**

```
StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava("هولاء كومو")
```

This class is available on: [Commons Lang from Apache](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/)

**Hope this helps!**

Answer (score 0):

Check the [HTTP Status Response Codes](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html). An error happened on the server, so the diagnostics will need to be performed on the server, not on the client.

Comment: I am getting 500 error means i can understand that server is not able to process my request. it will be great if u can help me to resolve this

Comment: You don't have the correct information for anyone to help you. Your post only references your client code, but the issue is on your server. Without seeing a stack trace from your server, no one can help with a diagnosis.

Comment: Hi we are getting the exception at SoapUi com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.DispatchException: java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: UCS-4